# Importing a GLSL file throws an error - Vite project

Tags: import, syntax-error, glsl, vite, unexpected-token

So Im currently playing around with three.js and have used vite to setup the document.
I've created a separate fragment.glsl so I dont have to write code inside the shadermaterial. But in the console i get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at fragment.glsl?import:1:13)
```

The fragment.glsl file looks like:

```
void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);
};
```

I tried importing the file from my /shaders/ folder using:

```
import fragment from './shaders/fragment.glsl'
```

And expected it to run the code when I used it in my shaders material:

```
this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            fragmentShader: fragment,
            uniforms: {
                progress: {
                    type: 'f',
                    value: 0,
                },
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            },
        })
```

But all i get is errors in the console. I cant seem to figure out what Im doing wrong. I didnt expect importing a file would be so troublesome. Does anyone see what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and solved it by installing [vite-plugin-glsl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-glsl). It has a simple setup instruction, after it was installed the import problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

First install a package:

```
npm i vite-plugin-glsl --save-dev
```

And then do some changes in `vite.config.js`:

```
import glsl from 'vite-plugin-glsl';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
```

Add on the top and then add another thing in the export default on the same `vite.config.js`:

```
plugins: [ glsl() ]
```

And then add this in the `package.json` in the dependencies part:

```
"vite-plugin-glsl": "^1.1.2"
```

And finally your work is completely done